# Determine Ipv6 address of another machine when I know its ipv4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

I'm using ubuntu and can use python if needed to try and find the ipv6 address of another computer. I already know the other computer's ipv4 address.

Previously, I had to find the mac address of this other computer and I used `arp -an <ip_addr>` and parsed for the mac address to return it. Is there anything similar that I can do via linux or python to search/ping by ipv4 and return more information of that host like its ipv6 address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a little luck, if you know the host name of the other machine, you might find the (link-local) IPv6 address by just pinging the host name. For example, `ping -6 otherhost`. This requires that the other computer is running a LLMNR or mDNS responder, and that the other computer is on the same LAN.

If you know the MAC address of the other computer, you can find out the link-local IPv6 address by using a converter, [this one](https://ben.akrin.com/?p=1347), for example.

Comment: Thanks! I'll follow those conversion steps with the mac address to get the ipv6 address.